# Determine coordinates for Mandelbrot set zoom.

Tags: geometry, fractals

I am writing a computer program to produce a zoom on the Mandelbrot set.  The issue I am having with this is that I don't know how to tell the computer where to zoom.  As of right now I just pick a set of coordinates in the complex plane and zoom into that point.  Only problem is that eventually it will either become completely light or dark because those coordinates are not exactly on the border of the fractal.  Any ideas for how to calculate the "most interesting" coordinates?

Comment: Explicitly determining the points on the boundary of the fractal is quite hard.  Check out [popular tourist areas](http://www.nahee.com/Derbyshire/manguide.html)

Comment: The issue is I need a way to have the program determine which areas are of interest.  Because it needs to zoom automatically.

Comment: How do you define "areas of interest"?  If you want the program to zoom automatically, you need some way to quantify what it means to be interesting.

Comment: I was maybe going to try for an area where it is not all dark or light

Comment: @chasep255:  you can try just clicking and zooming until you find an interesting point, then use smaller and smaller rectangles centered on that, ending at the final zoom where you found the point.

Comment: @chasep255 I am also learning how to build the Mandelbrot set and came across the following explanation which includes also details about zooming. There is a link to the code, so it might help you to enhance yours. Good luck! https://plus.maths.org/content/computing-mandelbrot-set

Answer (score 6):

One strategy to find some interesting (at least to my own subjective taste) places (which might not make interesting videos) semi-automatically is to spot patterns in the binary expansions of [external angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_ray), extrapolating these patterns to a greater length, and [trace external rays](http://www.math.titech.ac.jp/~kawahira/programs/mandel-exray.pdf) (rational angles/rays land on the boundary in the limit if I recall correctly) until they are near enough to switch to Newton's method.  Or use the spider algorithm (which I don't yet understand, nor do I know of any arbitrary precision implementations).

Define $f(z, c) = z^2 + c$.  You can find a minibrot island nucleus satisfying $f^p(0,c) = 0$ using Newton's method once you have the period $p$ and a sufficiently nearby initial guess $c_0$ for the iteration:

$c_{n+1} = c_n - \frac{f^p(0,c_n)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial c}f^p(0,c_n)}$

You can estimate if your ray end-point $c_0$ is near enough by seeing if $|f^p(0,c_0)| < |f^q(0, c_0)|$ for all $1 \le q \lt p$.

I wrote a [blog post on "navigating by spokes"](http://mathr.co.uk/blog/2013-02-01_navigating_by_spokes_in_the_mandelbrot_set.html) with one binary expansion pattern extrapolation idea, later posts describe some other patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Quick dirty answer: there are two circles, their boundary being zones of chaos. As a starter, you could explore those areas.

Another alternative would be to use a visualiser and a click tracker so you can select the coordinates using a mouse.

Comment: I have written one of those before.  Where I click and it zooms.  What I want to do is now make a video with thousands of frames so I wont be able to just click.  I need to automate the zoom.

Comment: Then, just click until you find a picture you like, and, then, go back and automate the zoom to that point.